# Java Memory with Windows 7 or Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, heap-memory, heap-size

I have installed 6GB ram on my Windows and 5GB memory free space and when I run a Java program with specifying Java heap space -Xmx2048m It's working fine. My question is, what if I have this on my Linux box

> cat /proc/meminfo

```
 MemTotal: 10.130464 kB (10.1gb)
 MemFree : 248.736 kB (248mb)
```

What will happen if I run the Java program with -Xmx2048m in Linux with this memory?

Comment: It will most likely run fine unless you have true resource constraints. The OS will do memory management including using swap space if necessary

Comment: I didn't try it. It may corrupt the linux memory or something will happen I'm scared.

Answer (score 1):

Java will allow the heap to grow to the Xmx value, but it won't necessarily start at or need to use that much.  Xms specifies the minimum heap size, which is how much heap memory Java will allocate right at the start.  Java will allocate additional memory for Perm Gen.  Any program, not just Java, will begin to fail if it needs more memory when there is none available.  Java in particular throws OutOfMemoryError when either Xmx is reached or there is no available memory on the machine.
MemFree is the amount of physical memory left, but that is not the total amount of available memory.  When physical memory is full, the operating system will use swap space (SwapTotal and SwapFree).  Swap space is usually on the hard disk and therefore very slow.  Linux would try to keep the most frequently used memory blocks in physical memory to maintain performance, but usually there is some slowdown.  It's likely the Linux box is already using some swap space considering there is a relatively small amount of free physical space left.  Combine MemFree and SwapFree to get your total available memory.
Edit: With 1.8GB total physical plus swap free, you would be able to start Java because it initially uses Xms (min heap) plus PermGen memory, which defaults to 220MB on 10GB of physical ram (1/64 physical memory plus 64MB PermGen).  As your program runs, it could use the rest of your available system memory, but only if your program actually needs it.  If this program is not resource intensive, it will likely stay in the lower end.  Typically you should set Xmx so that it doesn't use all your memory though. You may want to just close some other programs if your memory usage is that high.

Comment: I have 277716 kB ( 277mb ) for MemFree and for SwapFree 1397572 (1.4gb) So let's say I have 1.8gb therefore I can't do the -Xmx2048m? Even I have Installed Ram 10gb